# Exception Handling with akka.net PipeTo() on Task

Tags: c#, microservices, akka.net

Referring to Akka.Net documentation, using `PipeTo()` is preferred when dealing with asynchronous jobs.

When dealing with a function that returns `Task<T>`, I can handle the failure event, no problem.

The problem is, when dealing with a function that does not return any type, but only `Task`, one still calls the `PipeTo` function, but instead of having the overload which contains the failure handle, it now says the following: 'As this task has no result, only exceptions will be piped to the recipient.'.

Does this mean, if I have the following code:

```
public class RepositoryComponent : IRepositoryComponent
{
    private SqlSettings _sqlSettings;

    public RepositoryComponent(SqlSettings sqlSettings)
    {
        _sqlSettings = sqlSettings;
    }

    public async Task InsertJobAsync(RetryModel job)
    {
        try
        {
            await... //some logic
        }
        catch { throw; }
    }
}
```

My actor:

```
public class RepositoryActor : ActorBase
{
    private IRepositoryComponent _repoComponent;
    private ActorSelection _retryActor;

    public RepositoryActor(IRepositoryComponent repoComponent) : base()
    {
        _repoComponent = repoComponent;
    }

    public override void Listening()
    {
        Receive<RepositoryMessages.GenericRequestNoReturn>(x => InvokeRequest(x));
        Receive<RepositoryMessages.GenericRequestWithResponseType>(x => InvokeRequestAndSendResponse(x));
    }

    private void InvokeRequest(RepositoryMessages.GenericRequestNoReturn msg)
    {
        try
        {
            //some logic with msg
            _repoComponent.InsertJobAsync(new Core.Models.RetryModel()).PipeTo(Context.Self);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            base.ExceptionHandling(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

In order to catch exceptions in the above actor, I need to add another Receive handler to cater for exceptions, as for example, below:

```
Receive<Exception>(x => SomeExceptionHandler(x));
```

Is this correct?  If so, no need for the `try {} catch {}` around my code block?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're calling your asynchronous operation with `PipeTo`, it won't block your current code execution path. This means that the try/catch statement will never be executed (as success or failure of the task representing asynchronous operation will be redirected to `Self`).

There are 2 ways to handle exceptions that may happen during async operation execution:

1. Use `ReceiveAsync<>` instead of `Receive<>` in combination with async lambda - this will allow you to simply `await` for asynchronous operation to complete. You're free to use try/catch in this context, as it will work as expected. Keep in mind that this will keep your actor non-reentrant - it means, that the actor will not process any messages until current asynchronous operation completes.
2. Keep `PipeTo` and add another `Receive<>` handler in your logic - in case when a task wrapping asynchronous operation will fail, the exception will be wrapped into a message and redirected back to `PipeTo`'s target (`Self` in your case). By default exceptions produced this way are wrapped in `Status.Failure` message - in this case you'd need to add `Receive<Status.Failure>` handler in your actor. You can also specify a custom message constructor used to handle `PipeTo` failures i.e.: `_repoComponent.InsertJobAsync(input).PipeTo(Context.Self, failure: exception => new MyErrorMessage(exception))`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was under the impression if I use PipeTo() where the Task has no return type, the exception returned will handled in the receive event as follow: Receive<KeyNotFoundException>(...).  Thanks for your useful input